# C#, SingleLinkedList question about while loop

Tags: c#

I have few questions...

So I'm working with Single Linked List and I have some issues understanding the code.
So let's say I have something like this:

```
            public void addToEnd(int data)
        {
            Node p = start;

            Node temp = new Node(data);

            if (start == null)
            {
                start = temp;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                while(p.link != null)
                {
                    p = p.link;
                }

                p.link = temp;

            }
        }
```

So... This code will add Node at the end of the list. I get that. Let's check the display list method...

```
 public void displayList()
        {
            Node p = start;

            if (start == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("List is empty.");
                return;
            }

            while(p != null)
            {

                Console.Write("|" + p.data + "| -> ");
                p = p.link;

            }

        }
```

So my concern is this... In displayList method, while loop says  - ( while p != null ) ... I played with it a bit, and I changed it into - ( while p.link != null ). So result is that it wont print last element of the list. And so I got to conclusion that p.link is not last Node, but one before. It is just referring to the last Node of the list. So if my assumption is correct, how come that method addToEnd(int data) is working perfectly, and it's really adding some Node to the end if the wile loop in that method is - ( while p.link != null ). Shouldn't it like in case of displayList() method when I change the while loop point to the second last element of the list? If someone can explain this one to me that would be amazing. Thanks in advance guys ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods are correct, let's break down the elements:

1. *addToEnd* will add an element to the end of the linked list
2. *displayList* prints the whole list with format |{int}|->
3. *start* seems to be a class level Node that defines the first element of the list
4. The `Node` class has a `Link` property that links the *next* Node on the list (not the last)

Now, how does `displayList` work?

1. Declare a `p` variable that will have the node that the method is working with at any given time
2. Check if `p`, now that it's being assigned the start node, is empty, if it's empty a message is shown and the method ends, then
3. While `p` (the current element) is not null, print its value and then assign to `p` the next element on the list, which is `p.Link`
4. If the next element is null, the `while` exists and that's the end

The difference between the two methods is that `addToEnd` checks if the next node is null to assign `data` as the last element. `displayList` can't move to the next element until it has printed the current one.

Comment: I think I got it. I tried to print last Node after the while loop in displayList() method and it's said - p was null. But we cannot do that in addToEnd method, because we need last one, so we can make connection to the new last Node... That's why in addToEnd method in while loop it says - while (p.link != null ) ... It's basically saying if the Node's link is pointing to nothing stop there... Ok thank you so much Pedro!! I will mark you answer as the one who solved my problem! :))